# Java Spring return Javascript

Tags: java, javascript, spring, spring-mvc

I'm creating a Plugin that any website could embed and display, similar as Disqus. I already have a pretty good idea and understanding on how it works on the client side thanks to this post: [How to make a javascript like Disqus or IntenseDebate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3990167/how-to-make-a-javascript-like-disqus-or-intensedebate).

So the code I'm planning to use on the client side is similar with Disqus or Google Analytics:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        var user_id = 'anbmDj3ish43'; 

        (function() {
            var plug = document.createElement('script'); plug.type = 'text/javascript'; plug.async = true;
            plug.src = 'http://www.example.com/user/' + user_id;
            (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(plug);
        })();
</script>
```

For each page of the website The plugin displayed will be different so I need to change the content of the javascript code returned to the page (i.e. have to change the injected code, the design of the plugin,etc.).
I use JAVA and Spring framework for the back-end since the rest of the application use these technologies.

So my question is the following:
Inside my spring controller, what do I have to do to be able to return a javascript that will be understood by the browser? Or, I might be also on the wrong way and have to handle it a different way?

Below was one of my first guess but it sends back text/plain and it's not understood by the browser as javascript..

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = {"/user/"})
public class EmbedJavascriptController extends AbstractController{

    @Autowired
    private Service service;

    @Transactional
    @RequestMapping(value = "/{userId}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces="text/javascript; charset=utf-8")
    public String home(HttpServletRequest request,HttpSession session,
        @PathVariable("userId") String userId) throws Exception {

        return "console.log('I wanna load some scripts');";
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated :D

Comment: Generally speaking, that `script` tag would be in your HTML template, and you'd supply whatever arguments you need in your `Model`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue and resolved it using this technique.

You can return a **ModelAndView** which resolves to a `JSP` using a `InternalResourceViewResolver`. Your `JSP` could hold all of your `javascript` contents that you want to return. Add this line to the top of that `JSP`.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="application/javascript; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```

Comment: What if this JSP page contains only javascript in ECMA Script 6+, is correctly parsed the contentType from the JSP engine?